# Separar Recibos de Facturas

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

me encuentro en una situación en la que necesito vuestra ayuda, tengo un sistema de ventas realizado en Javafx (bueno es más parecido a un CRM), el caso es que en uno de los módulos es un sistema de facturación o ventas, lo que sucede es que por temas legales tengo que corregir o rehacer algunas entidades de la BBDD. os lo detallo:

**Tabla sale (Venta):** 
- sale_id
- sale_date
- sale_state
- customer_id
- employee_id
- sale_document (Factura - Recibo)
- sale_subtotal
- sale_discount
- sale_total

**Tabla product_sale**
- sale_id
- product_sale_id
- product_sale_name
- product_sale_unit
- product_sale_price
- product_sale_discount
- product_sale_tax
- product_sale_total

El caso es que por temas legales en mi pais las facturas deben ser correlativas por numero de serie y fecha, y es recomendable que los recibos sigan la misma regla (Aunque no es obligatorio, quiero respetarlo, para evitar problemas con clientes). Pues bien, el caso es que usaba como nº de factura el numero de ventas es decir id_sale, y esto me generaba saltos en la serie.

¿Como podría solucionar este problemas, es decir, tener independientes los números de las facturas de los recibos, añadiendo algun campo o crear otra entidad?

Comment: ¿Por qué una venta no tiene el mismo número de factura y recibo?

Comment: Porque las facturas tienen IVA y un cliente asociado, y lo recibos no los tienen, es como un comprobante de pago.

Comment: A que te refieres con saltos en la serie?

Comment: Cuando el realizo una nueva venta, el id de venta (id_sale) aumenta independientemente si es factura o recibo, por ejemplo: venta 1 (factura), venta 2 (recibo), venta 3 (factura), entonces la serie de la factura saltaria del numero 1 al 3, y para que sea legal tiene que tener factura 1, 2, 3 ... y así sucesivamente. no se si me explico. El caso es que la numeracion tiene que ser una para facturas y otra para recibos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que debes hacer es agregar un campo, numérico, no consecutivo, y generar tu el consecutivo a la hora de guardar una venta. Para esto debes usar LIMIT, [aquí](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) te dejo información sobre esto. Además aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
SELECT nFactura
FROM t_sales
LIMIT 1
ORDER BY nFactura DESC
```

Esto te seleccionará el último número, así entonces lo que debes hacer es guardar ese valor en una variable, sumarle uno y guardar dicho valor en la siguiente venta.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, lo he implementado como dices.